# Obtener el valor de un <select> con Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, materialize

Mi problema es que no consigo obtener el valor que tiene el `<select>`, aunque le pongo el atributo `v-model`a la etiqueta `<select>` y que en internet encuentro que es la manera correcta, no me funciona, cree este [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/Villatoro/pen/NYrvqL?editors=1010) para que me entiendan mejor y me puedan ayudar mas cómodamente.

Estoy utilizando `Materialize` y haciendo pruebas le quite el `css` a la pagina para ver que sucedia y curiosamente al seleccionar una `<option>` del `<select>` si tomaba el `value`, pero tengo que utilizar `Materialize`

Mi objetivo es obtener el `value` de la `<option>` que tiene seleccionada el `<select>`, espero puedan ayudarme.

También les dejo acá el fragmento de código, lo que tuviera que suceder es que al seleccionar algo, apareciera el `div` que tiene el `v-if`, si van al [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/Villatoro/pen/NYrvqL?editors=1010) de codepen y quitan la libreria `materialize` css notaran que si funciona pero al agregar el css de `materialize` deja de hacerlo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    elementos: [{
        value: '0',
        text: 'Seleccionar...'
      },
      {
        value: '1',
        text: 'Opcion 1'
      },
      {
        value: '2',
        text: 'Opcion 2'
      },
    ],
    seleccionado: ""
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #90a4ae;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>select vue ejemplo pregunta</title>


  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <div id="root" class="container">
    <br><br>
    <div class="card-panel blue-grey lighten-5">
      <form>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <select v-model="seleccionado">
                <option v-for="elemento in elementos" v-bind:value="elemento.value">{{ elemento.text }}</option>
              </select>
              <label>Materialize Select</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12" v-if="seleccionado != ''">
              <label>seleccionado: {{seleccionado}}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.js'></script>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: será mejor creeme si agregar aquí tu código y lo formateas con la herramienta del editor de textos que te ofrece stack over flow

Comment: Puedes agregar algo de código si lo tienes, o puedes mirar este link a ver si te es util https://es-vuejs.github.io/vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: por favor actualiza tu pregunta y agrega el código ya tengo la solución a tu ejercicio pero necesito se formalice tu pregunta

Comment: Publica la respuesta @ShadowPaz , puedes traer el código de CodePen y pegarlo en tu respuesta.

Comment: bueno es que me han penalizado por responder a cuestiones que no muestran justo aquí el código por eso lo decía

Comment: La diferencia en este caso es que sí existe un código, solo que no está aca en SO, pero puedes "importarlo" y agregarlo a tu respuesta.

Comment: Tienens algun error en la consola?

Comment: @ShadowPaz ahora lo agrego, estaba fuera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar Refs, así:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <select ref="seleccionado">
        <option v-for="elemento in elementos">{{elemento.text}}</option>
    </select>
<label>Elementos</label>
```

Y en tu data:{}

```
elementos: [{
    otrasPropiedades: 'aaa',
    text: 'Seleccionar...'
    },
    {
    otrasPropiedades: 'bbb',
    text: 'Opcion 1'
    },
    {
    otrasPropiedades: 'ccc',
    text: 'Opcion 2'
    },
],
```

Cuando quieras almacenar el value entonces puedes usar:

```
this.seleccionado = this.$refs.seleccionado.value;
```

dentro de los methods.

PD: Puedes acceder a más elementos del select además del .value, solo inspecciona qué elemento quieres.

Edit: Esto con Vue 2, no estoy seguro sin con Vue 1 funciona.

Comment: Pero el `this.seleccionado = this.$refs.seleccionado.value;` lo pondre dentro de los methods o dentro de una funcion que se ejecute cuando el select cambie?

Comment: Esto puede que solucione el problema, pero estariamos violando lo que hace VUE... que es justamente que las variables sean reactivas. Alguna idea de porque no esta pasando el valor de la variable? obviamente es algo de materialize, pero parece un bug desde algun lado...

Comment: @gbianchi en el chat hablamos :)

Comment: Dejo algunos links. el problema es materialize. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33704122/73749 ; https://stackoverflow.com/q/47201651/73749; https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html

Comment: Okey @gbianchi Aver que dicen, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo, al parecer para utilizar Vue.js con Materialize en algunas cosas causa conficto... pero con este codigo que agregue en el evento `mounted` lo solucione y ya pude obtener el `value` de la `option` seleccionada.

```
var vue = this;//vue

$('select').material_select();

$('#vueSelect').on('change', function () {
    vue.$emit("change", this.value)
});

vue.$on("change", function(data){
    this.seleccionar.value = data
});
```

aqui les dejo el ejemplo completo:

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: "#root",
 data: {
    seleccionar: {value: ""},
    elementos: [
        { value: '1', text: 'Opcion 1' },
        { value: '2', text: 'Opcion 2' },
      ],
    seleccionado: ""
 },

    mounted:function() {
        var vue = this;//vue

        $('select').material_select();

        $('#vueSelect').on('change', function () {
            vue.$emit("change", this.value)
        });

        vue.$on("change", function(data){
            this.seleccionar.value = data
        });
    }
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #90a4ae;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>select vue ejemplo pregunta</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root" class="container">
   <br><br>
   <div class="card-panel blue-grey lighten-5">
     <form>
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="input-field col s8">
              <select id="vueSelect">
                <option selected disabled value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
                <option v-for="elemento in elementos" v-bind:value="elemento.value">{{ elemento.text }}</option>
              </select>
              <label>Materialize Select</label>
            </div>
           <div class="input-field col s4" v-if="seleccionar.value != ''">
             <label>seleccionado: {{seleccionar.value}}</label>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </form>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.js'></script>
  <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo para obtener el valor de un select ocupo esto:

```
div id="app" class="container mt-5">
        <!--
            aqui estamos ocupando lo que selecionado del select o insertamos en el input mediante una variable
            #:class: nos permite agregar clases dinamicas dentro de una etiqueta.
            #['clase-normal', claseDinamica] //Esto es un array de clases o puedes usar solo esto
            #:class="clase-normal" 
        -->
        <p :class="['p-3', 'text-white', fondo]">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nam culpa ipsa omnis sapiente deleniti sint voluptatum dicta provident consectetur. Odit consequatur molestias facilis minima dicta explicabo natus deleniti eligendi atque!
        </p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <!--
                Esto es para mandar el valor del input a una variable en data
                data: {fondo: 'bg-danger'}
                <input type="text" v-model="fondo">
            -->

            <!--
                Esto es para mandar lo que selecionemos dentro del select a una variable de data
                #v-model es donde se enviara o la variable que ocuparemos
                #v-bind:value es el valor que se enviara a v-model 
                <select v-model="fondo"> 
                    <option v-bind:value="bg-primary">
                        data: {fondo: 'bg-danger'}
            -->
            <select class="form-control" v-model="fondo">
                <option 
                    v-for="background of backgrounds"
                    v-bind:value="background.background">{{background.text}}
                </option>
              </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Este es el archivo JS

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        backgrounds: [
            {
                background: 'bg-danger', 
                text: 'Fondo Rojo'
            },
            {
                background: 'bg-primary',
                text: 'Fondo Azul'
            },
            {
                background: 'bg-success',
                text: 'Fondo Verde'
            }
        ],
        fondo: 'bg-danger'
    },
    methods: {

    }
})
```

Comment: Debes de añadir mas contenido a tu respuesta. Justificarla un poco, de por que usas ese codigo